# Dirichlet Distribution unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, dirichlet

Does anyone has reliable data that I could use to write some unit tests for a new implementation of the Dirichlet distribution?

Answer (score 1):

One of the topic modeling techniques is LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) is based also based on the Dirichlet distribution (document-topic distribution and topic-word distribution). You can use news articles to find topics.[Link of the CSV data containing Nepali news articles](https://www.kaggle.com/anilkrsah/kathmandu-post-article). You can refer to the [following link to get through its implementation](https://www.kaggle.com/anilkrsah/topic-modeling-test).